# What's the grammar behind "with eight minutes elapsed"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, grammar, word-choice

> "In the second half they shot 33 percent and we got up and guarded
>   people," he said. "I'm proud of the second half, but we don't do moral
>   victories around here."
>
> NCCU led 7-6 early and was tied at 10 `with eight minutes elapsed`.

Source: [No. 19 Maryland cruises past NC Central 67-56](http://collegebasketball.ap.org/hhcourier/article/no-19-maryland-cruises-past-nc-central-67-56)

In my English learning, the acceptable version should be `with eight minutes elapsing or with eight minutes having elapsed` because elapse is intransitive verb, so I became confused here how elapsed had been used.

Comment: **go** is similarly intransitive and we often use **gone** as a post-modifier to describe the absent or used-up state of something:  "With their rations *gone*, they had to hunt for food."  *With the sunlight gone, they had to use torches to see the path.*

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I can understand gone because it can function as an adjective.

Comment: *With the insurance policy lapsed, they had to pay for the damages out-of-pocket.*  *With 89 minutes elapsed, they had only a minute to tie the game.*   **having** is not necessary when we have a prepositional phrase introduced by **with** and a past participle used as a post-modifier indicating state.   Their policy having lapsed....With their policy lapsed.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo could you list more of examples that used this grammar structure. My most understanding hindrance is that elapse is a intransitive verb.

Comment: But even an intransitive verb has a past participle which indicates state. You can think of this as "With their policy [being] lapsed", that is, as a non-finite clause indicating the state the policy is in.  The state of the minutes of the game clock is elapsed.

Comment: With their friends departed....Their friends [being] departed.  With the colors faded.... With the colors [being] faded... With the ice melted they could boat across the river.  With the ice [being] melted...  Now that the ice was melted.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo you mean I can add being before elapsed. Why is it being not having?

Comment: I am indicating a semantic property with `[being]`: the state now. You can certainly say **having elapsed**. Nothing wrong with that. I am responding to your question in which the assumption is that the absence of **having** is "unacceptable".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Thanks ever so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

- *With* is a preposition
- *Minutes* is the object of the preposition *with* - a noun.
- *Eight* is an adjective modifying *minutes*
- *Elapsed* is the past participle form of *elapse*, being used as a modifier, post-positively modifying *minutes*.

  This construct is common - "X Y'ed" is equivalent to "X that
  am/is/are/was/were Y'ed" or "X that have/has/had been Y'ed"
  typically.

Comment: If so, it is equivalent to *minutes that has been elapsed*. But elapse is an intransitive verb, which is not used in passive voice.

Comment: @Kris: The past participle is used in passive construction, true, but that is not the only way it is used.